# Spring Data REST in plain JSON (not HAL format)

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

How exactly should Spring Data Rest be configured to return plain JSON instead of HAL (JSON with Hypermedia like links)

Related

- [Spring returns Resource in pure JSON not in HAL Format when including spring data rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639659/spring-returns-resource-in-pure-json-not-in-hal-format-when-including-spring-dat)
- [Spring Data Rest -Disable self links(HAL) in Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274067/spring-data-rest-disable-self-linkshal-in-json)
- and big [Disable Hypertext Application Language (HAL) in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264044/spring-data-rest-disable-hypertext-application-language-hal-in-json-applica)
- using [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org/) instead of HAL [Changing the JSON format for spring-data-rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844686/changing-the-json-format-for-spring-data-rest)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

for me `spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType=application/json` does not take effect. But it can be approched by programmed config, like below :

```
    public class SpringRestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {

            config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            config.useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly the same for me, worked programmatically.

Answer (score 15):

Add the below property to your application.properties or yml . By default it is application/hal+json

> spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType=application/json

Comment: this instead of producing a simple json produces a json containing the links

Comment: In my case it is already with that value, but I still see `_embeded` in response

Comment: Here is more accurate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23287265/4151158